# Can't create an iOS project with auto layout

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm on a mac using OS X 10.7.5 and Xcode 4.3.3, and the option to use auto layout or constraints is unavailable to me when I start an empty or single page project.  [This is what the Interface Builder Documents window looks like for me](http://i.gyazo.com/1d120e7c1a4d651c1e01071e1e238a17.png)

Is there a setting I forgot to select to enable Auto Layout?  If not how do I enable it? (Clicking Reset Locking Controls does nothing)

Answer (score 2):

Your screen shot reveals that you are making an iOS project. Auto Layout for iOS projects was not introduced until Xcode 4.5. You are using Xcode 4.3.3, which is earlier.

So, to see the Auto Layout option for an iOS project, you would need to update to at least Xcode 4.5. (Quite honestly, I can't recommend using anything earlier than Xcode 5.1.1; certainly when trying to use Auto Layout in Xcode 4.5 you will be working with one hand tied behind your back, as support was quite rudimentary.)

Comment: I think Xcode 4.3 had the auto layout but in this case it's the deployment target is the problem. I don't think there was auto layout with iOS 5

Comment: @Desdenova You could be right - you should give that as an alternate answer! I have no copy of 4.3.3 to try it with so I had to go partly by memory and partly by dribs and drabs on the net...